# crosscompile: undefined reference to std::__atomic_futex_unsigned_base::_M_futex_notify_all(unsigned int*) when linking

Tags: c++, linux, arm, c++14, cross-compiling

I want to crosscompile tiny-dnn(a c++14 project, https://github.com/tiny-dnn/tiny-dnn ) on arm platform.
so I installed g++-arm-Linux-gnueabi and gcc-arm-Linux-gnueabi, the version is GCC5.4.
Then I modified the CMakeList to add some flags.

```
option(ARM "Crosscompile with arm" ON)
if(ARM)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabi-g++)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
endif()
```

Then I added some flags:

```
-march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a9 -mfpu=neon
```

finally, all the flags(some flags show twice) are:

```
-O3 -DNDEBUG -O3 -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a9 -mfpu=neon -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -static -pthread -Wall -Wpedantic -Wno-narrowing -Wno-deprecated -Wall -Wpedanitc -Wno-narrowing -Wno-deprecated
```

finally I have got these error:

> [ 6%] Building CXX object
>   examples/CMakeFiles/example_mnist_train.dir/mnist/train.cpp.o [ 12%]
>   Linking CXX executable example_mnist_train
>   CMakeFiles/example_mnist_train.dir/mnist/train.cpp.o: In function
>   std::__future_base::_State_baseV2::_M_set_result(std::function ()>, bool) [clone
>   .constprop.5599]': train.cpp:(.text+0x584): undefined reference
>   tostd::__atomic_futex_unsigned_base::_M_futex_notify_all(unsigned
>   int*)' CMakeFiles/example_mnist_train.dir/mnist/train.cpp.o: In
>   function
>   std::__future_base::_State_baseV2::_M_set_result(std::function ()>, bool) [clone
>   .constprop.5600]': train.cpp:(.text+0x67c): undefined reference
>   tostd::__atomic_futex_unsigned_base::_M_futex_notify_all(unsigned
>   int*)' CMakeFiles/example_mnist_train.dir/mnist/train.cpp.o: In
>   function `std::__future_base::_Result::~_Result()':

...etc

It seems that it can't refer to the std lib. Did I miss something?

BTW, I can compile the project on both Nvidia TX1 and Raspbian Pi, so the project should be compatible with ARM.

Comment: What do you see when you type `/path/to/your/gcc/lib/libstdc++.a  | grep _M_futex_notify_all` ?

Comment: I typed `sudo cat ./libstdc++.a | grep  _M_futex_notify_all`, didn't get matches. Tried the code on ordinary gcc, got binary matches. so should I try some other cross-toolchain or compile one on my own.

Comment: Sorry typo, my bad. You need `nm -C /path/to/your/gcc/lib/libstdc++.a | grep _M_futex_notify_all` (and why on earth sudo?!)

Comment: tried the new code, return nothing. Tried the code on ordinary GCC, return: `00000000000000 T std::__atomic_futex_unsigned_base::_M_futex_notify_all(unsigned int*) U std::__atomic_futex_unsigned_base::_M_futex_notify_all(unsigned int*)`

Comment: Can you find any other function in the arm library, e.g. `nm ... | grep basic_string`?

Comment: Yes, `grep | basic_string` works in the arm lib.

Comment: So it looks like this version of gcc/libstdc++ doesn't have the futures feature implemented yet, at least on ARM. Perhaps try to download a newer version.

Comment: This is suspicious though, as if it's not in the library it shouldn't be in the headers either. Perhaps there's a header/library version mismatch.  At any rate try downloading a newer gcc-arm version.

Answer (score 1):

Check how was your gcc compiled using `gcc -v`. If architecture required via `-march` flag used by your project does not match `--with-arch` value used for gcc compilation, it may cause issues similar to one you are referring to.

In that case, you may need to get another toolchain and runtime for your platform.

`gcc -v` will give output similar to the one below, check the `--with-arch` flag in Configured with section:

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: arm-linux-gnueabi
Configured with: ... --with-arch=armv5t --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=arm-linux-gnueabi ...
gcc version xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe the linked library is error. you can assign the link flag with -L int cxx or c flags.

in the new version gcc, gcc -v , not show --with-arch.

Comment: How is this different from the highest-voted answer?